# Android Pre Dex compiler hanging in Intellij - needs to allocate more memory?

Tags: android, scala, intellij-idea

I am trying to build a scala android project using sbt and then import to Intellij. I can build and run through sbt no problem. I then imported into Intellij but when I try to compile it hangs every time in the Make at:

> Pre-dex: scala-compiler-2.11.7.jar

I have examined the build.log and it I see the line:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Is there a way I can allocate more memory to the Pre Dex compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the memory in File/Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Android Compilers. There you can give additional options to the VM for Dex. So adding -Xmx4096M seems to have resolved my memory issue. Default is 1024M

Comment: Note that the options don't always stick the first time for some reason so you may need to compile more than once before they work, strangely. You can see if they take affect by inspecting build.log